# how to pass list of sql scripts files to psql using -f option

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to know if we can pass list of sql script files using psql command.

I have test1.sql,test2.sql,test3.sql files and right now i am executing these files individually in a loop

```
psql -f D:\\test1.sql postgresql://postgres:secret@localhost:5432/testdb
```

I want to know if there is any way to pass all three files to the psql command and psql should execute it sequentially.

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this, read [this helpful DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/source-several-files-at-once-with-psql) article.

Comment: `-f D:\\test1.sql -f D:\\test2.sql -f D:\\test3.sql`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-f` parameter multiple times:

```
psql -f D:\\test1.sql -f D:\\test2.sql -f D:\\test3.sql postgresql://postgres:secret@localhost:5432/testdb
```